# I am trying to sort this table by user_meta org and right now it sorts by username.

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to sort this table by user_meta 'org' and right now it sorts by username. Please help. Thanks!

```
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
        <?php
        // Get all users order by amount of posts
        $allUsers = get_users('order=ASC');

        $users = array();

        // Remove subscribers from the list as they won't write any articles
        foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
        {
        if(!in_array( 'administrator', $currentUser->roles ))
        {
        $users[] = $currentUser;
        }
        }

        ?>

        <?php get_header(); ?>


        <?php


        foreach($users as $user)
        {
        ?>

        <tr>
        <th><?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'org', true); ?></th>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $user->first_name . " " . $user->last_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'pnumber', true); ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $user->user_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $user->user_url; ?></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
```

I am trying to loop through account names and meta info and put them in the order_by user_meta org. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a start could be to use the orderby parameter of the query in get_users. But it only works for the following fields: 'ID', 'login', 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', or 'post_count' for example:

```
$allUsers = get_users('order=ASC&orderby=ID'); // the default orderby is login
```

(see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

But if I understood correctly, seems like what you actually need to do is something like

```
$users[] = $currentUser;
$user_org = get_user_meta($currentUser->ID, 'org'); // read user_meta org
$user[count($user-1)]->org = $user_org;
```

(see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

in your control structure and then re sort the array according to the 'org' value. How? http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Sorry I didn't actually test the code just an idea. Did you manage? (if so please mark my answer as useful :D)

Comment: I read the articles you had referenced and I didn't do exactly what i wanted but I just matched the org to the nickname and changed the display name to the nickname and changed the orderby=display_name Thanks Jorge!